# Sorting the contact name based on the company identifier in ios programmatiically

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts, import-contacts

I want to display the contact name along with the company identifier.Suppose first name is john and company is ABC the contact should be displayed as john ABC. is it possible using addressbook o anything in ios programmatically.

Comment: yes, this seems possible.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to grab the records you want using `ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople()`, which returns a `CFArrayRef` or 
filter some subset from of them using `NSPredicate`
then grab the name:

```
NSString *name = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(record,kABPersonFirstNameProperty));
```

and the company

```
NSString *company = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(record,kABPersonOrganizationProperty));
```

then use those values as you wish.  For more details look at [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/DirectInteraction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH6-SW1)